# No sound in Webview

Tags: android, audio, webview, webchromeclient

i have the Problem, that i have no sound at webview.
On the native Browser on android the sound is working.

The sound is a Flash.

If you want to see, you can open http://www.colourmonics.de/android/android16

Here is my Script:

```
package C.K;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;


public class ColourmonicsKeyboardActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    WebView mWebView;   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
         audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);   
         if (savedInstanceState != null){
             ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
         } else {       
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);    
         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
         mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
         mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.colourmonics.de/android/android16");
         }
    }
    private AudioManager audio;
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

      @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had simular problem. I wolvee this with adding javascriptinterface to my webview. Then call a methode that play sound in native Java.